# aumentar o tamanho dos números matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gráfico

Como posso aumentar o tamanho dos números do gráfico (os que estão marcados nos eixos x e y) no matplotlib? Similar a alterar o tamanho da fonte.

Comment: Bom, está explicado o problema. Ele é simples. Não é necessário tantos detalhes. É um problema específico conceitual sobre matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o comando `plt.tick_params(labelsize=30)` para aumentar o tamanho da fonte nos eixos do gráfico, substituindo `30` pelo tamanho desejado.

### Exemplo

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math

# Dados de exemplo -- sen(x) calculado de 0 a 10
x = [v/10.0 for v in range(0, 100, 1)]
y = [math.sin(v) for v in x]

# Gráfico 1 - Tamanho da fonte normal
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()

# A próxima linha é responsável por aumentar o tamanho da fonte nos eixos
plt.tick_params(labelsize=30)

# Gráfico 2 - Tamanho da fonte aumentado
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

### Resultado

- 1º gráfico com tamanho da fonte normal
- 2º gráfico com tamanho da fonte aumentada

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]